# Requerying SQL Cursors on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Related: [SQL cursors in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241313/sql-cursors-in-android)

Cursors retrieved through SQL functions don't notify observers when the data on disk changes. What is the best way to watch for changes to tables in the database? Right now I'm maintaining a global list of `DataSetObserver`s that all get notified when the data changes.

Also, `Cursor.requery()` is deprecated. What is the best way to get a new Cursor that contains the most up-to-date data? I've created an interface `CursorProvider` that can provide a new Cursor as needed.